# CodeBlocks Crashed on Mac

Tags: macos, osx-lion, codeblocks

I have just installed CodeBlocks on my mac book air. My OS X version is 10.7.2. I have encountered some problems. Everytime when I select "Settings > Editor" and click "ok", my CodeBlocks crashed. And when I closed it, it pop up the message "The CodeBlocks terminated unexpectedly." (Sorry, I am not sure what the message of the English version is, because my locale is Traditional Chinese.) Does anyone knows what happend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the same problems.
However the thread
[Making compiler setting stick in Mac OS X](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13266.0)
showed me the way out. I figured out the 'wxSmith' plugins seem to be the source of my trouble.
I disabled them under: Plugins > Manage Plugins

Answer (score 2):

I solved't disabling **Code completion**!

**Step 1:** Open **Manage plugins...**

[image: Step 1: Open Manage plugins...]

**Step 2:** Disable **Code completion**.

[image: Step 2: Disable **Code completion**.]